# C++/Openssl Get RSA key from encoded bytes (encoded by java)

Tags: java, c++, encryption, cryptography

Does somebody know how I can create an RSA key in C++ from an encoded byte array?

My problem is that I try to develop a C++ client that is interacting with a server which is coded in Java.
Well in Java the client receives the rsa key encoded as an byte array, decodes it to a RSA RSAPublicKey and encrypts a message with this key.

The java server/client code:

```
public static PublicKey decodePublicKey(byte[] p_75896_0_)
{
    try
    {
        X509EncodedKeySpec var1 = new X509EncodedKeySpec(p_75896_0_);
        KeyFactory var2 = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return var2.generatePublic(var1);
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException var3)
    {
        ;
    }
    catch (InvalidKeySpecException var4)
    {
        ;
    }

    field_180198_a.error("Public key reconstitute failed!");
    return null;
}

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

this.publicKey = CryptManager.decodePublicKey(data.readByteArray());
```

After that the client is doing some encrypting stuff with his key.

The key gets sent like this:

```
public static final KeyPair keys;
static
{
    try
    {
        KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance( "RSA" );
        generator.initialize( 1024 );
        keys = generator.generateKeyPair();
    } catch ( NoSuchAlgorithmException ex )
    {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError( ex );
    }
}

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
byte[] pubKey = keys.getPublic().getEncoded();
writeBytes(pubKey);
```

My problem is how to get the key from the byte array in C++.

**Update:**
Im currently working on this code:

```
    char* publicKey = ...
    int publicKeyLength = 162;
    EVP_PKEY* key = EVP_PKEY_new();

    if(d2i_PUBKEY(&key, (const unsigned char**) &publicKey, publicKeyLength) != 0){
        logError("Problem!");
    }
    logMessage("Key: "+to_string((uint64_t) (void*) key));
```

Well my problem now is that i have an SIGSEGV error on the third line and dont know what this course. Well the key should be valid.

Comment: Did you settle on a library to do this? Otherwise, this question is really broad, because there are many ways to do this.

Comment: Well i prefer OpenSSL. Well but if you have a better solution or libary i will be take a look at this.

Comment: OK, so have you opened the [API documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/) to see which functions might be helpful in this case? `PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey` might be a good way to start.

Comment: Yep, but the problem is that i dont have an file/string with the key. I yust have the raw encoded bytes

Comment: You don't need a file. There's an option to a BIO.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I think this was asking for the public key, rather than the private key (transferring the public key makes more sense as well).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes That's how I understood it too, but then I copied the wrong function name.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Yep, I know that feeling, you take the time to look everything up and then you still copy the wrong text :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Java returns for the public key is a SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure, which doesn't just contain the (PKCS#1 encoded) values for the public key, but also the key identifier etc.

So to decode this you have to type "decode SubjectPublicKeyInfo openssl" in your favorite search engine. Then you'll find (after some scrolling) the following information from [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/i2d_PUBKEY_bio.html):

> ```
> d2i_PUBKEY() and i2d_PUBKEY() decode and encode an EVP_PKEY structure
> using SubjectPublicKeyInfo format. They otherwise follow the conventions
> of other ASN.1 functions such as d2i_X509().
> ```

Obviously you'd need the decoding algorithm.

---

Note that openssl is C so beware of buffer overruns when decoding stuff. I'd rather have a 1024 bit RSA key that is used with secure software than a 2048 bit key with software full of buffer overruns.

Needless to say you need to *trust* the public key before importing it. There is a reason why it is called the public key *infrastructure* (PKI).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, i will try it again when im at home. I already tried it with this methode but i got every time an error so i thought that java dosnt export the key in the SubjectPublicKeyInfo stucture.

Comment: It certainly does. Make sure you open the file in binary mode.